# Does measurement invariance analysis assume equal latent scores across groups?

Tags: latent-variable, measurement, invariance

I have completed a measurement invariance analysis comparing high-school aged boys to high-school aged girls on a measure of depression. The results suggest that scores are *not* (scalar) invariant; girls tend to report more severe depression symptoms than their "actual" depression level would indicate. Moreover, the results indicate that girls report more severe symptoms than their actual depression level would indicate (i.e., have higher latent intercepts) *on every item* when compared to boys.

I am struggling to understand how this method can distinguish between (a) scalar measurement variance, i.e., groups systematically over- or under-reporting depression symptoms, and (b) actual differences in depression within the sample. When estimating participants' latent depression scores, we only have their responses to go off of, so how can we conclude that they over- or under-report their depression level on *every item*? The only way I can imagine coming to this conclusion is by first assuming that the true latent means in both groups are equal (i.e., that boys and girls in this sample are equally depressed) - is this assumed?

Answer (score 2):

In the metric invariance model (invariant loadings but non-invariant intercepts) latent means are typically not estimated (i.e., they are fixed at zero in all groups and therefore "equal" across groups). If there are any true mean differences, they would be confounded with differences in the intercepts in the metric model.

The way that latent mean vs. observed intercept differences become separable is when you assume (at least partial) intercept invariance across groups. With (at least partial) intercept invariance, you can estimate latent means and allow for latent mean differences across groups.

When the scalar model is rejected, this does not necessarily mean that *all* intercepts differ between groups. Perhaps you have partial invariance where at least a few intercepts are the same across groups. Then, you could still distinguish between true (latent) mean differences and (some) intercept differences.

If all items differ in their intercepts, there is no way to distinguish between latent mean differences and observed mean differences. In that case, you would be comparing apples and oranges. Meaningfully comparing latent means requires that at least one or two intercepts are truly invariant across groups.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes intuitive sense to me. To clarify: when you say "assume partial intercept invariance", you are refering to a case where you assume that intercepts for specific item(s) are invariant across groups; this gives you a benchmark against which you can measure the performance of other items. Is that right?

Comment: As a corollary: If one group has truly different latent means on every item (e.g., more depressed per each symptom), one cannot establish scalar invariance?

Comment: Scalar invariance can hold even when all items differ in their means across groups (as long as those mean differences can be explained by latent factor mean differences alone). This is one of the very purposes of an invariance analysis--to find out whether differences are due to latent (true score) differences or due to differences in the origin and/or units of the measurement instrument.

Comment: That makes sense in theory, but you seem to be saying in practice there may be no way to determine this, no?

Comment: It is not just theoretical. You determine this through model fit testing. When the scalar model fits well, this would indicate that any observed variable mean differences between groups are reflecting "true score" (latent factor) mean differences. When the scalar model does not fit, and all intercepts are different between groups, then you cannot interpret mean differences as latent mean differences because the scales have a different origin of measurement (different difficulty) across groups.

Comment: In between full and zero intercept invariance is partial invariance where some intercepts are and others aren't invariant. Partial invariance may be sufficient to meaningfully interpret latent factor mean differences depending on how many variables show intercept invariance. See, e.g., Byrne, B. M., Shavelson, R. J., & Muthén, B. (1989). Testing for the equivalence of factor covariance and mean structures: the issue of partial measurement invariance. Psychological Bulletin, 105(3), 456-466.